# Check if siblings in an unordered list of inputs are checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, siblings

I have an unordered list of checkbox inputs:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox">parent
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox">child
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox">grandchild
            <ul>
              <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">great grandchild</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox">great grandchild</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox">great grandchild</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">great grandchild</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

If I uncheck one of the checkboxes, how can I check if any siblings are also checked only from that `<ul>`?

I've tried a number of things such as `siblings()`, `find()` and `index()`.

Comment: You'd need to use a selector too. `.siblings(':checked')` that will return all siblings that are checked.

Comment: ul within a ul within a ul within a ul

Comment: 4 levels? Impossible.... `:)`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children(":checkbox:checked").length
```

This should get you the number of "sibling" checkboxes which are checked.